# Setting up Continuous Integration with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, continuous-integration

I have a number of applications that I am looking to use CI on, as the test suites are becoming large enough that running it manually is becoming unwieldy.

As these are client applications rather than gems, there's a fair few dependencies such as Postgres, Redis, Memcache etc.

Now, it doesn't make any sense to me to stub this stuff out in my tests as I'm not really then testing the application properly.

Therefore, what's the best way to set this sort of thing up? Create a server with all the required dependencies installed and setup for the apps, or something else?

This question isn't 'which CI', but how to deal with the dependencies.

Comment: travis-ci is the way to go apparently

Comment: I should add that none of these codebases are open-source, being client applications.  Additionally  Travis won't give me any configuration past the bundled set of services.

Comment: you could have a look at jenkins https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuring+a+Rails+build it's not written in rails but this guide should help you set it up for rails

Comment: CruiseControl: https://github.com/thoughtworks/cruisecontrol.rb

Comment: Another approach - to use as you expected the CI server, and on them use Capybara/Selenium tests. For example [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)

Comment: OK - This question isn't 'which CI', but how to deal with the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these are more related to configuration management, it is better to use tools such as [Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home) or [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) for the setup. You can use this along with [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Documentation-v2.x) to automate the setup. Railsmachine's [Moonshine](https://github.com/railsmachine/moonshine) combines both Capistrano and Puppet and it is easy to configure.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a hosted service, such as [Circle](https://circleci.com) (disclaimer: I'm a founder of [Circle](https://circleci.com)). We have most of the dependencies pre-installed, and allow you to install extra packages if you need them. So you wouldn't stub anything out, and it's much easier than writing Chef or Puppet or capistrano - in fact, you don't need to write anything at all.